# Changing spinner launch icon

Tags: android, icons, spinner, android-3.0-honeycomb

I want to change spinner down arrow to custom `.png` file.
    I found code [here](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57) but it doesn't work in android 3.0.

Please provide some help.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
mSpinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

Comment: It will change background of spinner i don't want it but I want to change the dropdown icon to something else.